# Aws Cloudwatch Logs agent throws an error

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm setting up awslogs agent on ec2 instance, When i run the python script of awslogs. I'm getting below message.

Downloading the latest CloudWatch Logs agent bits ... ERROR: Failed to create virtualenv. Try manually installing with pip and adding it to the sudo user's PATH before running this script.

And **awslogs-agent-setup.log** show below error.

**Environment**: CentOS 6.10 and Python 2.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py2.6.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 92
    _blocking_errnos = {errno.EAGAIN, errno.EWOULDBLOCK}
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
/usr/bin/virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 51, in <module>
    print("ERROR: {}".format(sys.exc_info()[1]))
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this error is due to your python version 2.6. Could you please update your python version from 2.6 to **2.7 or 3.1**.

This should help.

Comment: Centos relies on python 2.6 for yum, It may break my system, If switching to 2.7 globally.

Comment: Agreed. You can refer to this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4.